# _WebTryThreadLock error

Tags: ios4, uiwebview, ipad

I am facing an error while manipulation the UIWebView in ipad application. in that I have to fill the UIWebview with the HTML string and though the content is coming from the APi so I have to implement the process under Thread.
Below is the error message :

**bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xb2aa410: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are doing some graphical changes in secondary thread .. you must do all the graphical changes in your main thread. check you thread code.

Comment: yes, as per the requirement. It will not have scroll on the UiWebView so I have to change the height of that control as per content.

also Today I have found the same error while changing the frame of UIScrollView like 

[scrComments setFrame:CGRectMake(lblSummary.frame.origin.x, lblSummary.frame.origin.y + lblSummary.frame.size.height + 10 , lblSummary.frame.size.width, scrComments.frame.size.height)];

Comment: you can't do graphical (UIKit) changes in a secondary thread!

Comment: yes I agree, but how can I handle this situation. I mean if the I need to display some text in UIWebView and that is too long to download so I have to use thread and now the size of the UIWebView will depends on the content height. I am facing the same issue with UILabel

Comment: you can use this method - [self performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)aSelector#> withObject:<#(id)arg#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)wait#>];